# Grep multiple "and" expressions UNIX

Tags: unix, grep

I have been trying to find an answer for this question, but I have had difficulty getting a clear answer. Hopefully someone can assist.

I wanted to grep two patterns in a single or multiple files hoping the command will grep only files with both of the below patterns:

```
grep 35=[D|F|G] | 1=Account1 .log
```

I would like all `35=D,F,G` messages that contain account `1` in `.log`

Hopefully someone can assist and thank you in advance.

Comment: Please provide some sample input and the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

Is the problem that you want to find files that contain two strings, but the strings won't be on the same line? If so, I just learned that today!

```
grep -l "first pattern" <files> | xargs grep -l "second pattern"
```

The first grep passes a list of file names to the second. `xargs` takes each of those filenames and passes them as an argument to the second grep.

Comment: Or check [the answers under the `awk` tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/awk?sort=votes).